# jqGrid not in Tree mode Why?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a problem with jqGrid . jqGrid version 4.2.0 - jQuery Grid
grid show loaded data not in tree mode, only grid mode. Why ? 
Please help me ! Можно по русски .
Add in header

```
   <link href="../jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-ru.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and my function to get data from web service .

```
   function getDataSC(pData) {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/FetchData.asmx/bindSCJson") %>',
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success")
            ReceivedClientDataSC(JSON.parse(getMain(data)).rows);
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus) {
        alert('An error has occured retrieving data!');
    }
});
}
function ReceivedClientDataSC(data) {
    var thegrid = $("#gridSC");
    thegrid.clearGridData();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        thegrid.addRowData(i + 1, data[i]);
}
function getMain(dObj) {
    if (dObj.hasOwnProperty('d'))
        return dObj.d;
    else
        return dObj;
}

var lastSel;
$("#gridSC").jqGrid({
datatype: function(pdata) { getDataSC(pdata); },

treeGrid: true, 
treeGridModel : 'adjacency',
ExpandColumn: 'Name',
ExpandColClick: true ,
mtype: 'POST',
treeIcons: {plus:'ui-icon-circle-plus',minus:'ui-icon-circle-minus',leaf:'ui-    
 icon-person'},

height: "100%",
width: 900,
     colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'CountryName', 'Town', 'Adress', 'Phone', 'Email', 
'Url'],
     colModel: [
                    { name: 'Id', index:'id', width:10, hidden:true,key:true},
                    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 80},
                    { name: 'CountryName',index:'CountryName', width:80},
                    { name: 'Town', index: 'Town', width: 20 },
                    { name: 'Adress', index: 'Adress', width: 90 },
                    { name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 20},
                    { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 20 },
                    { name: 'Url', index: 'Url', width: 30}
                  ],
       pager: $('#pjmapSC')
       //rowNum:20,
       //viewrecords: true,
       //gridview: true,
       //rowList:[10,20,30,100],
       //sortname: 'Id',
       //sortorder: 'asc'

    })

    }
```

json from server service (loaded to grid) :

```
{"d":"{\"total\":1,\"page\":1,\"records\":2,\"rows\":[{\"err\":null,\"Id\":1,\"Parent  
 \":0,\"Name\":\"Сервисные центры\",\"CountryCode\":103,\"Town\":\"Киев\",\"Adress
 \":\"Красных партизан 1\",\"Phone\":\"123-321\",\"Email\":\"mail@mail.ru 
 \",\"CountryName\":\"United Arab Emirates\",\"Url\":\"www.service1\",\"isLeaf\":false,
 \"Expanded\":true,\"Level\":1},{\"err\":null,\"Id\":2,\"Parent\":1,\"Name
 \":\"Сервисный центр 1_1\",\"CountryCode\":103,\"Town\":\"Киев\",\"Adress\":\"Артема
 \",\"Phone\":\"123-321\",\"Email\":\"fert@ukr.net\",\"CountryName\":\"United Arab  
 Emirates\",\"Url\":\"www.service2\",\"isLeaf\":true,\"Expanded\":true,\"Level\":2}],
 \"userData\":null}"}
```

Help Please ! Thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks Oleg ,  but i try change my server string to

```
{"d":{"__type":"_admin.JqGridData","total":3,"page":1,"records":26,"rows":        [{"id":1,"cell":["1","Сервисные центры","United Arab Emirates","Киев","Красных партизан 1","123-321","mail@mail.ru","www.service1","0",null,"False","False"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","Сервисный центр 1_1","United Arab Emirates","Киев","Артема","123-321","fert@ukr.net","www.service2","1","1","True","False"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Сервисный центр 1_2","United Arab Emirates","Донецк","Артема","123-321","fert@ukr.net","www.service2","1","1","True","False"]},{"id":5,"cell":["5","Сервисный центр 1_3","United Arab Emirates","Одесса","Артема","123-321","fert@ukr.net","www.service3","1","1","True","False"]},
```

and

```
   $("#gridSC").jqGrid({
   url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/FetchData.asmx/bindSC") %>',
   datatype: 'json',
   mtype: 'POST',
   treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
   ExpandColumn: 'Name',
   ExpandColClick: true,
   ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
   serializeGridData: function (postData) {
     if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
     if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
     if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
    //if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
     return JSON.stringify(postData);
  },
 jsonReader: {
     root: function (obj) { return obj.d.rows; },
     page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
     total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
     records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; }
  },
  colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'CountryName', 'Town', 'Adress', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Url'],
  colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'id', width: 10, hidden: true, key: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 80 },
                { name: 'CountryName', index: 'CountryName', width: 80 },
                { name: 'Town', index: 'Town', width: 20 },
                { name: 'Adress', index: 'Adress', width: 90 },
                { name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 20 },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 20 },
                { name: 'Url', index: 'Url', width: 30 }
              ],
  rowNum: 10,
  rowList: [10, 20, 300],
  sortname: 'Name',
  sortorder: "asc",
  pager: "#pjmapSC",
  viewrecords: true,
  gridview: true,
  rownumbers: true,
  height: "100%",
  caption: ''
  })
```

and test
       treeReader : {
       level_field: "level",
       parent_id_field: "parent",
       leaf_field: "isLeaf",
       expanded_field: "expanded"
      },
nothing change in grid (not tree grid) . In server side my method

```
        int startIndex = (page - 1) * rows;
        int endIndex = (startIndex + rows < recordsCount) ?
                       startIndex + rows : recordsCount;
        List<TableRow> gridRows = new List<TableRow>(rows);

        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
        {
             gridRows.Add(new TableRow()
               {
                id = lsc[i].Id,
                cell = new List<string>(11) {
                    lsc[i].Id.ToString(), 
                    lsc[i].Name, 
                    lsc[i].CountryName,
                    lsc[i].Town,
                    lsc[i].Adress,
                    lsc[i].Phone,
                    lsc[i].Email,
                    lsc[i].Url,
                    lsc[i].level.ToString(),
                    lsc[i].parent,
                    lsc[i].isLeaf.ToString(),
                    lsc[i].expanded.ToString()
```

if i change to this 
                //string.Format("Name:{0}", lsc[i].Name)
my grid load incorrectly data

Help please.

---

Thanks Oleg ,  but i try change my server string to

{"d":{"__type":"_admin.JqGridData","total":3,"page":1,"records":26,"rows":        [{"id":1,"cell":["1","Сервисные центры","United Arab Emirates","Киев","Красных партизан 1","123-321","mail@mail.ru","www.service1","0",null,"False","False"]},{"id":2,"cell":["2","Сервисный центр 1_1","United Arab Emirates","Киев","Артема","123-321","fert@ukr.net","www.service2","1","1","True","False"]},{"id":4,"cell":["4","Сервисный центр 1_2","United Arab Emirates","Донецк","Артема","123-321","fert@ukr.net","www.service2","1","1","True","False"]},{"id":5,"cell":["5","Сервисный центр 1_3","United Arab Emirates","Одесса","Артема","123-321","fert@ukr.net","www.service3","1","1","True","False"]},

and

```
   $("#gridSC").jqGrid({
   url: '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/FetchData.asmx/bindSC") %>',
   datatype: 'json',
   mtype: 'POST',
   treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
   ExpandColumn: 'Name',
   ExpandColClick: true,
   ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
   serializeGridData: function (postData) {
     if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
     if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
     if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
    //if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
     return JSON.stringify(postData);
  },
 jsonReader: {
     root: function (obj) { return obj.d.rows; },
     page: function (obj) { return obj.d.page; },
     total: function (obj) { return obj.d.total; },
     records: function (obj) { return obj.d.records; }
  },
  colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'CountryName', 'Town', 'Adress', 'Phone', 'Email', 'Url'],
  colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'id', width: 10, hidden: true, key: true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 80 },
                { name: 'CountryName', index: 'CountryName', width: 80 },
                { name: 'Town', index: 'Town', width: 20 },
                { name: 'Adress', index: 'Adress', width: 90 },
                { name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 20 },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 20 },
                { name: 'Url', index: 'Url', width: 30 }
              ],
  rowNum: 10,
  rowList: [10, 20, 300],
  sortname: 'Name',
  sortorder: "asc",
  pager: "#pjmapSC",
  viewrecords: true,
  gridview: true,
  rownumbers: true,
  height: "100%",
  caption: ''
  })
```

and test
       treeReader : {
       level_field: "level",
       parent_id_field: "parent",
       leaf_field: "isLeaf",
       expanded_field: "expanded"
      },
nothing change in grid (not tree grid) . In server side my method

```
        int startIndex = (page - 1) * rows;
        int endIndex = (startIndex + rows < recordsCount) ?
                       startIndex + rows : recordsCount;
        List<TableRow> gridRows = new List<TableRow>(rows);

        for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
        {
             gridRows.Add(new TableRow()
               {
                id = lsc[i].Id,
                cell = new List<string>(11) {
                    lsc[i].Id.ToString(), 
                    lsc[i].Name, 
                    lsc[i].CountryName,
                    lsc[i].Town,
                    lsc[i].Adress,
                    lsc[i].Phone,
                    lsc[i].Email,
                    lsc[i].Url,
                    lsc[i].level.ToString(),
                    lsc[i].parent,
                    lsc[i].isLeaf.ToString(),
                    lsc[i].expanded.ToString()
```

if i change to this 
                //string.Format("Name:{0}", lsc[i].Name)
my grid load incorrectly data

Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You main error is in the wrong case of the column names of Tree Grid which you use. It should be `level`, `parent`, `expanded` instead of `Level`, `Parent`, `Expanded` which you use in the JSON input. Only `isLeaf` you use correctly. So you should either correct the column which use your web service or add parameter [treeReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadjacency_model#treereader_configuration) which describes the names which you use:

```
treeReader = {
   level_field: "Level",
   parent_id_field: "Parent",
   leaf_field: "isLeaf",
   expanded_field: "Expanded"
}
```

Additionally I would recommend you to change your code so that you use `datatype: 'json'` instead of `datatype` as function.